# How to copy packages from old hard drive to new one?

Tags: package-management

My server runs a very old version of Ubuntu (no longer supported). It's too old to upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu (I tried), but it's still sufficient for my needs.

The root partition on my primary drive finally gave up the ghost. I reinstalled Ubuntu onto my backup drive from CD, but in the process lost all the software I'd installed (including vim and who knows what else).

Other than manually copying executables from the old /usr/ partition to the new one is there a way to copy all of the installed software to the new one?

Edit: I see that `dpkg --root=/mountpoint -l` will list the packages that were installed on the old system.

Comment: If the old drive is readable, consider using Clonezilla.

Comment: Lots of steps system:(multiple upgrades from old, current server with added packages, current desktop remove packages); system config; user packages: (identify, configuration, data migration), each will get lots of opinions. But there'll be no disagreement that its' a bad idea to run old, unpatched software on a server. Maybe a forum is a better place for this.